# JWT Validation - Signature validation failed. Token does not have a kid

Tags: c#, .net, validation, jwt, azure-functions

I've been working lately on the JWT Validation in .NET/C# and it almost works (worked yesterday at least :)). When I validate the token, I am getting an exception

> IDX10503: Signature validation failed. Token does not have a kid. Keys tried: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityKey, KeyId: 'T1St-dLTvyWRgxB_676u8krXS-I', InternalId: 'T1St-dLTvyWRgxB_676u8krXS-I'. , KeyId: T1St-dLTvyWRgxB_676u8krXS-I
> '. Number of keys in TokenValidationParameters: '1'.
> Number of keys in Configuration: '0'.

```
string stsDiscoveryEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration";
        ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration> configManager = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(stsDiscoveryEndpoint, new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever());
        OpenIdConnectConfiguration config = configManager.GetConfigurationAsync().Result;

        TokenValidationParameters validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidAudience = "XXX",
            ValidIssuer = "XXX",
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = config.SigningKeys.FirstOrDefault(),
            ValidateLifetime = true
        };

        JwtSecurityTokenHandler tokendHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        SecurityToken jwt;
        tokendHandler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out jwt);
```

When I decode the Access Token I am using for Validation, I can see the KID is there, although not the one that is found in the configuration.

```
{
    "typ": "JWT",
    "alg": "RS256",
    "kid": "5B3nRxtQ7ji8eNDc3Fy05Kf97ZE"
}
```

EDIT:
Can this be related to saved singing keys in memory (for example from yesterday) that are out of sync with what I am trying to validate today? If so, how can I flush the singing keys from the configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I remember you can create `ConfigurationManager` singleton, but before validating the token you should call the `GetConfigurationAsync()` to keep it up to date. The config is kept in memory and after a certain interval it will refresh the information.

Then set your signing keys using `IssuerSigningKeys = config.SigningKeys,` instead of only using the first. Since there can be multiple valid keys.

Comment: I am actually blind. I haven't seen the "IssuerSigningKeys" where I can put all the keys from configuration. Thanks!